# Function v8::Value::IsInt32 has no address

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, v8, embedded-v8

I"m trying to debug C++ coding with embedded V8 using Visual Studio 2015.   First I tried to enter this expression in the QuickWatch window:

```
value->IsInt32()
```

*(value is of type `Local<Value>`)*

But then it said this:

> class "v8::Local" has no member "IsInt32".

Ok, so then I figured perhaps `->` is implemented in a special way, so I tried it directly on the wrapped pointer field instead:

```
value->val_->IsInt32()
```

Ad got this:

> Function v8::Value::IsInt32 has no address, possibly due to compiler optimizations.

Both V8 AND my C++ wrapper project are compiled in debug mode.  I tried static linking as well, but same thing.  Is this not possible?

Answer (score 0):

There are gdbinit and lldbinit files in the v8 repo (in tools). They help a lot with debugging Locals. Make sure you have `v8_optimized_debug = false` in your gn config. Otherwise you'll get an optimized debug build.